# Reading excel data of custom data type in excel to load in to data set but it's truncating the decimal value using oledb provider

Tags: c#

I tried and fed up with the problem.

Actually I have a requirement of excel sheet containing Custom format in Excel.
While loading into dataset the decimal value has 0.123456 but its dispalying as 0.1235.

oledb connection string is having Imex=1, HDR=Yes. I need header and the data has to be displayed as 0.123456.

Can you please help me on this.

Comment: This may simply be a display issue in Excel - have you tried changing the cell format to display 6 decimal places to see if it displays correctly or has really been rounded to 4dp.

Comment: You say:  _" its dispalying as 0.1235"_, but _where_ is it displaying incorrectly?  In Excel?  Are you reading the data _from_ Excel or sending the data _to_ Excel?  What library are you using?  In order to help you we need a lot more information.